# Java - Applet Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jar, applet, policy

I have a Java project that contains 1 JApplet.
I'm able to run the Applet in desk-top mode (adding the applet to a frame in main[] method).
It doesn't work in a browser though. Getting this error:
I already signed all the jars.

I believe its related to mysql connector jar.

Any ideas?

```
Exception occurred: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (uncaught)"thread=AWT-
EventQueue-1", java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(), line=156 bci=152
```

It runs fine if I add grant all to java.policy

Comment: Please paste the HTML used to launch the applet, the entire stack trace, and at least the part of your code that is the first lines mentioned in the stack trace, identifying their line number.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure:

- That your [applet is signed](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) to allow for database connections.
- That your mysql connector jar is available on your 'download' path just like your applet jar file.

Comment: I just followed those steps: http://www.narendranaidu.com/2007/11/3-easy-steps-to-self-sign-applet-jar.html how do I sign for db connections?

Answer (score 0):

Running the application from a webserver solved the issue.